# How to read unbuffered UTF-8 in Perl

Tags: perl, utf-8, buffering

I'm trying to read UTF-8 input in Perl in an unbuffered way (i.e. as soon as data is available, it should be returned):

```
die if !binmode STDIN, ':unix:utf8';
my $i;
my $buf;
while ($i = read(STDIN, $buf, 8192)) {
  print "$i\n";
}
```

However, it doesn't work if the input contains an UTF-8 character split:

```
$ perl -e '$|=1;print"\xc3";sleep 1;print"\xa1";sleep 1;print"AB"' | perl t.pl
```

This should print 1 and then 2, but it prints 3, so the buffering is withholding the first character even after it became available.

Is there an easy solution for this in Perl? Or maybe in another scripting language for Unix?

Comment: I don't think you should mix :translators and binary `read`. first `read` your buffer, then `Encode::decode` it. Exactly because the byte string `"\xc3"` is not an UTF-8 character.

Comment: There is no "unnecessary buffering" if you are reading an utf8 stream. You have to have at least a 6-to-8-bytes buffer so you don't read incomplete characters (that is what perl is doing in your example). And **that's** because I'm talking about codepoints. Glyphs are another story altogether.

Comment: you can very well do `binmode STDIN, ':raw'; binmode STDOUT, ':raw'` since you are not doing any other processing to your buffer. Even incomplete utf8 chars will be reassembled in the other side of the pipe.

Comment: @Massa: I'm doing processing, but that's not indicated in the example code.

Comment: @Massa: If I change AB to ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP in the example, Perl still returns everything in one batch. Thus the buffer size is larger than 8 bytes. And there is unnecessary buffering, because without unnecessary buffering my example should print 1 and 2, but it prints 3.

Comment: Are you doing per codepoint processing? or just "generic" processing? Because if you are doing per codepoint processing, you will need to buffer utf8-partials, because else you'll skip some codepoints. (@ikegami 's answer below shows you how)

Comment: @Massa: Yes, partials have to be buffered. That's necessary buffering, and I'm fine with it. I only want to avoid unnecessary buffering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to change from `read` to `sysread`. `read` reads until it has the requested number of chars, while `sysread` returns as soon as data are available.

But returning data as soon is arrives means you might have an incomplete UTF-8 character at the end, so you'll have to decode only characters fully received and buffer the rest.

```
sub decode_utf8_partial {
   my $s = decode('UTF-8', $_[0], Encode::FB_QUIET);
   return undef
      if !length($s) && $_[0] =~ /
         ^
         (?: [\x80-\xBF]
         |   [\xC0-\xDF].
         |   [\xE0-\xEF]..
         |   [\xF0-\xF7]...
         |   [\xF8-\xFF]
         )
      /xs;

    return $s;
}

binmode($fh);

my $buf;
while (1) {
   my $rv = sysread($fh, $buf, 64*1024, length($buf));
   die $! if !defined($rv);
   last if !$rv;

   while (1) {
      # Leaves undecoded part in $buf    
      my $s = decode_utf8_partial($buf);
      die "Bad UTF-8" if !defined($s);
      last if !length($s);

      ... do something with $s ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, this is the best so far. It does the unbuffered decoding if the input is valid. I couldn't make this fail with an error if the input is invalid (rather than incomplete).

Comment: read on a :unix handle doesn't re-read ordinarily, so the sysread doesn't matter. The :utf-8 layer was screwing things up in this case.

Comment: Not getting any errors is because you explicitly ask for it with `Encode::FB_QUIET`. You could sort-of solve that by using `Encode::FB_CROAK` if you're at file-end. But really, Encode should handle this cleaner by being able to separate invalid from incomplete.

Comment: @Leon Timmermans, no, that won't do. You'd be accumulating in $buf from the point where the error occurred until the end of the file. (And it would be simpler to do `die if length($buf)` outside the loop.)

Comment: @Leon Timmermans, `read` can block when data is available, so that's why `sysread` is used. That's the only difference between the two. Since he wants `sysread`'s behaviour, he should be using `sysread`. I disagree about your comment that it doesn't matter.

Comment: read can be made non-blocking.  it would be very unsatisfactory if perl didn't support non-blocking layer-based decoding.

Comment: @ysth, huh? The OP wants blocking, but only when there's no data available. This has nothing to do with non-blocking handles.

Comment: if you pretend for a minute that sysread doesn't exist, it has a *lot* to do with non-blocking handles.  sysread does get you the "block only when no data" semantics, but AFAICT at the cost of using IO layers; select & non-blocking read solves the problem *with* IO layer support.

Comment: @ysth, 1) You can't use buffered IO (i.e. `read`) with `select` -- it can report no data is available when there is sone -- so you'd still have to use `sysread`. 2) If `:utf8` can't handle a partial character using one form of non-blocking read, why do you think it could using another? 3) Why are you telling me there are other ways of doing it? This should be a comment to the OP or an answer of its own. Again, the comment to which you replied has nothing to do with non-blocking handles, and neither does my answer.

Comment: re 1), select should not report no data when there is some (unless some has been pushed back on the buffer, but in this case that should only happen with a partial character, and select should report data later when it is completed).  the obverse is not true, but not a problem, per se.  what makes you say otherwise?  re 2), not sure I understand your question  re 3) because you assert that yours is the only possible approach ("you need to change from read to sysread")

Comment: select could not report data available if you had some available but didn't read it all; you are right that that would have to be handled.

Comment: @ysth, "not sure I understand your question", You said "`select` & non-blocking read solves the problem with IO layer support", but that's not true. Substituting one form of non-blocking read for another doesn't help at all. You still can't use `:utf8`. `perl -e'$|=1; print chr 0xC3; sleep 10; print chr 0xA9' | perl -we'binmode(STDIN, ":utf8"); STDIN->blocking(0); <STDIN>'` gives `utf8 "\xC3" does not map to Unicode at -e line 1, <STDIN> line 1.`

Comment: @ysth, I never said it was the only possible approach, though I can't think of one that doesn't use `sysread`. Your approach also uses `sysread`. (I don't count using `read` and praying that it behaves like `sysread` to be an alternative to using `sysread`.)

Answer (score 1):

In utf-8 mode, read does a retry on partial characters. That kind of ruins your particular use of read-on-:unix though. I guess this is a case of "Don't do this".

In this particular case, `getc` may be of use. That will read the minimum necessary. In other situations, decoding afterwards may be a better option.

Comment: Yes, `getc` indeed doesn't do any buffering, but it calls *read(2)* to read a single byte for each invocation, which makes it too slow.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, though you will almost certainly want to throw in a sleep (perhaps Time::HiRes::sleep) or select into the loop:

```
die if !binmode STDIN, ':unix:utf8';
use IO::Handle;
die unless STDIN->blocking(0);
my $i;
my $buf;
while (1) {
    $i = read(STDIN, $buf, 8192);
    if ($i) {
        print "$i\n";
    }
    elsif (defined $i) {
        last;
    }
}
```